# How to get unlimited scroll in giphy api using jQuery & PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, giphy, giphy-api

I am looking for GIPHY scroll exactly like how FaceBook allows in create post. Currently scrolling down to bottom only displays a total of 25 GIFs. That is ok based on GIPHY API limits, however, it should continue to scroll but it does not. Below is my code. I have tried using limit & offset parameters as described [here](https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api/endpoint#search).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="search for GIFs" onkeyup="Wo_GetPostStickers(0,this.value)">

<div id="imageWrapper"></div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        offset = 0;
        // initial value for offset
        offsetVal = 0;
        // set your limit
        giphyLimit = 25;
        // getGiphy(0);
        $('#imageWrapper').scroll(function () {
            if ($('#imageWrapper').scrollTop() == $('#imageWrapper').height() - $(window).height()) {
                getGiphy(offset);
            }
        });
    })

    var Wo_Delay = (function(){
      var timer = 0;
      return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();

    var Wo_ElementLoad = function(selector, callback){
        $(selector).each(function(){
            if (this.complete || $(this).height() > 0) {
                callback.apply(this);
            }
            else {
                $(this).on('load', function(){
                    callback.apply(this);
                });
            }
        });
    };


    function Wo_GetPostStickers(i, keyword){
        if (!keyword) {
            //return false;
        }
        if (i > 0){
            // increase the offset with item limit like 25, 50 to get the next items
            offsetVal = giphyLimit*i;
        }

        Wo_Delay(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {q:keyword,api_key:'my_key', limit: giphyLimit, offset: offsetVal},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if (data.meta.status == 200 && data.data.length > 0) {
                    $('#imageWrapper').empty();
                    var appended = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                        appended = true;
                        if (appended == true) {
                            appended = false;
                            $('#imageWrapper').append($('<img alt="gif" src="'+data.data[i].images.fixed_height_small.url+'" data-gif="' + data.data[i].images.fixed_height.url + '" autoplay loop>'));
                            appended = true;
                        }
                    }
                    // increase offset to get further items.
                    offset = offset+1;
                    var images = 0;
                    Wo_ElementLoad($('img[alt=gif]'), function(){
                        images++;
                    });
                    if (data.data.length == images || images >= 5) {
                        alert('data');
                    }
                } else{
                    $('#imageWrapper').html('<p class="no_gifs_found"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="frown" class="svg-inline--fa fa-frown fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M248 8C111 8 0 119 0 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S385 8 248 8zm0 464c-119.1 0-216-96.9-216-216S128.9 40 248 40s216 96.9 216 216-96.9 216-216 216zm0-152c-44.4 0-86.2 19.6-114.8 53.8-5.7 6.8-4.8 16.9 2 22.5 6.8 5.7 16.9 4.8 22.5-2 22.4-26.8 55.3-42.2 90.2-42.2s67.8 15.4 90.2 42.2c5.3 6.4 15.4 8 22.5 2 6.8-5.7 7.7-15.8 2-22.5C334.2 339.6 292.4 320 248 320zm-80-80c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32-32 14.3-32 32 14.3 32 32 32zm160 0c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32-32 14.3-32 32 14.3 32 32 32z"></path></svg> No result</p>');
                }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
        },100);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add further item when scroll reaches to the bottom of the page/div

Here is your html to add content you will get from ajax

```
<div id="imageWrapper"></div>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
    $(document).ready(() => {
        let offset = 0;
        // initial value for offset
        let offsetVal = 0;
        // set your limit
        let giphyLimit = 25;

        function getGiphy (i){
            // if offset is greater than one then fetch further items prior to previous ones
            if (i > 0){
                // increase the offset with item limit like 25, 50 to get the next items
                offsetVal = giphyLimit*i;
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {q:'keyword',api_key:'api_key', limit: giphyLimit, offset: offsetVal},
                success: (data) => {
                    $.each(data['data'], ( index, value) => {
                        let imageUrl = value['images']['original']['url'];
                        $("#imageWrapper").append("<img width='500' height='300' src='"+imageUrl+"' />");
                    })
                    // increase offset to get further items.
                    offset = offset+1;
                }
            })
        }
        getGiphy(0);
        $(window).scroll(() => {
            // when scroll reaches to bottom.
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                getGiphy(offset);
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will try today and update you

Comment: it repeats all giphy except 1st every time

Comment: I have updated my answer. The offset is supposed to be the number of items that we have already fetched and the api will provide further giphs after that offset. Please try this one and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes this works but I want this in modal, where in input box I will write keyword and then search giphy related to this keyword.

Comment: Add a keyup function on your input field and the rest will be the same. Just change the scroll to that specific div height.

Comment: I have updated my code.. can you help me with this? I am using wowonder script..

Comment: Finally with some changes your code helped me to do my task. Thank you for your help.